# mysql_escape_string PROBLEM

Tags: wp-admin, mysql

I tried to put a plugin into my website. But, the moment I activate it, it gives me this message: [image: error message]

I went to `functions.php` and I saw this. Please, can anyone can help me? Thank you.
[image: functions.PHP]
My apologies for my English.

Comment: don't use plugins that generate errors

Comment: Your theme (not plugin) is very, very much out of date.

Comment: Contact your plugin author. They have to update it. It seems too old.

Comment: Not really, my theme was created last january, it is in themeforest. And the plugin was updated a month ago

Answer (score 0):

All the `mysql_` functions were deprecated in PHP 4.3 and the only currently supported version of PHP where it's still available is 5.6. These functions have been completely removed in PHP 7. Switch to using `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead.

Comment: imo - you should use the WordPress solutions.  Use: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql  Or:  $wpdb->prepare  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: Very nice. I'm a bit of a Wordpress n00b. Like modifying code...